# HTML button not disappearing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the result button to disappear on press but i cannot. I'm not understanding what the problem is here?

Also how would i pass arguments entered into n1 and n2 fields into my jQuery script?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>

        <title>javascript: calculate two numbers</title>
        <meta charset="windows-1252">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <h1> A Basic Calculator</h1>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#result").click(function(){
           $("#result").hide();
          });
         });
     </script>

    <body>
        <b>Enter Number 1:</b>
        <input type="text" id="n1"/><br/><br/>
        <b>Enter Number 2:</b>
        <input type="text" id="n2" name="n2"/><br/><br/>

        <select id="operators">
            <option value="+">+</option>
            <option value="-">-</option>
            <option value="/">/</option>
            <option value="X">X</option>
        </select>

        <button id="result">=</button>
        <input type="text" id="result"/>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: your code works for me on jsfiddle...are you successfully able to find jquery-3.3.1.min.js...do you have that file in the same folder?

Comment: Note that `id` **must** be unique, you have 2 elements with an id of *result*. Are you getting any console errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should restructure your code to use a `<form>`, and use vanilla javascript instead of jQuery (you seem to be having an import issue):

```js
document.querySelector('form#calculator').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const n1 = this.querySelector('input#n1').value
    const n2 = this.querySelector('input#n2').value
    const operator = this.querySelector('select#operators').value
    const result = eval(n1 + operator + n2)

    this.querySelector('button#result').style.display = "none"
    this.querySelector('input#result').value = result
})
```

```html
<form id="calculator">
  <b>Enter Number 1:</b>
  <input type="number" id="n1" name="n1" required /><br/><br/>
  <b>Enter Number 2:</b>
  <input type="number" id="n2" name="n2" required /><br/><br/>

  <select id="operators">
      <option value="+">+</option>
      <option value="-">-</option>
      <option value="/">/</option>
      <option value="x">x</option>
  </select>

  <button id="result">=</button>
  <input type="text" id="result"/>
</form>
```

Comment: @STOPIMACODER in addition to the `form`, notice the `type="number"` and `required` as they will prevent you from making the button disappear without having a value in those input fields

Comment: If there is no serverside interaction, why should they restructure with a `form` element?

Comment: @JonP Because the `<form>` element gives access to the `submit` event, which allows you to better target elements from the parent via `this.querySelector()`

Answer (score 0):

There are two HTML elements with id `result` so firstly I suggest you change them up:

```
<button id="result">=</button>
<input type="text" id="result-field"/>
```

Input values can be extracted using their IDs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#result").click(function(){
      $("#result").hide();
      let n1val = $("#n1").val();
      let n2val = $("#n2").val();
      // do something with the values
     });
});
```

Comment: would the script be at the end of the body? Because it is not doing anything.

Comment: Yes, as Hybrid pointed out in his answer, it's better to put it at the end of the body tag. However, I tested your code with the script at the beginning and the button disappeared as expected. Are you getting an error in the console?